# Choose kernel from the terminal when launching jupyter notebook. Can it be done?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

The command:

```
jupyter notebook blah.ipynb
```

will launch the notebook. But I want it to use a specific kernel called `my_fav_kernel` (it is listed in kernel > change kernel menu).

Can I change the CLI incantation I use to invoke `jupyter` to directly use 
`my_fav_kernel`  instead of having to mouse-click 
kernel > change kernel menu >  my_fav_kernel every time?

Answer (score 3):

If you save the notebook after selecting a kernel, the next time your notebook will start with your selected kernel.

Alternatively, something like the following works for me:

```
jupyter notebook --MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name=my_fav_kernel
```

Check [Jupyter documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The [Jupyter documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) discusses this. Search the page for the following:

```
NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class : Type
Default: 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.MappingKernelManager'
```

Here is an example of how to use it; you will probably need to provide the full package for `my_fav_kernel`:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class=my_fav_kernel blah.ipynb
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Have you been able to make this work?

Comment: I am unable to test with your kernel. Why don't you try?

Comment: I ask because I could not make it work. But it's not specific to my kernel: 'my_fav_kernel' is a default kernel I just created with virtualenv.

Comment: No idea what the problem(s) you are facing might be. Often solving one problem reveals others. You might want to accept this answer and ask a more detailed question so that others can reproduce the new problem you are facing.

Comment: have you been able to make this work with *any* non default kernel?

Comment: All I did was find documentation for you, and provide you with an example of syntax.